# Arrange characters of an array in the order they appear in the string java

Tags: java

I have an array of some characters from a string and the string. I want to arrange the characters in the order they appear in the string. For example:
Array a consists of s, o , e and the string is house. I want the result to be "ose". I tried using the Arrays.sort method but it returns the alphabets in the alphabetical order.

Comment: One way: Create a `Comparator<Character>`, and base its logic on the char positions within the String

Comment: btw I wonder what if character in string exists twice - like `y` in  'anybody'

Answer (score 6):

You could use this overload of `sort`:

```
Arrays.sort(chars, Comparator.comparingInt(str::indexOf));
```

given `chars` is of type `Character[]` and `str` is the `String`.

Comment: @snr test it with `Character[] chars = new Character[]{'s','e','o'};
           String str = "house";
           Arrays.sort(chars, Comparator.comparingInt(str::indexOf));`

Comment: @snr I cannot reproduce that error you're getting, seems to work fine. Are you using java 8?

Comment: i get this error when i place my string in place of str. "The type String does not define indexOf(Object) that is applicable here"

Comment: That was my mistake, it's ok now

Comment: @Learner see my previous comment to #snr for an example.

Comment: @Learner Be sure to select Java 8 in the settings when using this solution, that's the error you get when you don't have Java 8 selected.

Comment: i am using eclipse. how do i select java 8?

Comment: @Learner go through this tutorial -->  [Trying Out Lambda Expressions in the Eclipse IDE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/lambda-1984522.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have in the array **only** characters from a string you can actually count how much of every character do you have in the array and then iterate over the string adding to the new collection specific count of that character

```
String string = "house";
List<String> chars = Arrays.asList("s", "e", "o", "o")
Map<String, Integer> characterCount = initializeMapWithCharsAndZeroes(chars);

for(String character : chars) {
    characterCount.put(character, characterCount.get(characterCount)+1);
}

for(String character : string .split("")) {
    for(int i = 0; i < characterCount.get(character); i++) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom comperator:

```
class MyComperartor implements Comparator<Character> {
    private static String pattern = "house";

    public int compare(Character c1, Character c2) {
        return pattern.indexOf(c1) - pattern.indexOf(c2);
    }
}
```

and sort the array:

```
Character[] array = { 'e', 's', 'o'};
Arrays.sort(array, new MyComperartor());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

will print:

```
[o, s, e]
```